# Converting string of strings to list in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe as following:

```
id|words
1|ant,bat,cat
2|mat,rat,pat
```

I want the words column to be as follows:

```
id|words
1|['ant','bat','cat']
2|['mat','rat','pat']
```

How could I do it?
I tried with literaleval but it shows exception

Comment: dupe not match, reopened.

Comment: @jezrael why you think that is not dup ? from what I saw only the sep is different

Comment: @YOBEN_S - Answer is about first value of splitted separator.

Comment: @jezrael before they get the first value , it save whole list I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['words'] = df['words'].str.split(',')
```